# How to run word add-in using internet explorer 11 after update (Windows 10 ver. >= 1903 / Office 365 ver >= 16.0.116291)

Tags: office-js, word-addins

My system got updated to below version of windows OS and Office 365.
Windows 10 ver. >= 1903 / Office 365 ver >= 16.0.116291
I want to open the word add-in using internet explorer 11 (the way it was loading before) due to some xyz reason. As per [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins) we can use runtime, but when I used inside manifest it is showing below error.

[image]

So any help around how to run word add-in using internet explorer 11 after update (Windows 10 ver. >= 1903 / Office 365 ver >= 16.0.116291)

Comment: You need to be on Version 2002 (Build 12527.20092) or later to use a shared runtime. See [Shared Runtime Requirement Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/shared-runtime-requirement-sets).

Comment: Thanks for reply @RickKirkham.
This is compile time error in manifest file not runtime, so do you think office version will matter at compile time ? although my office build version is 2002 (Build 12527.20880).